# Prove that $\sin nx\le n\sin x$, by Induction

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inequality, solution-verification, induction

I have to prove that $\sin nx\le n\sin x,\ \forall n\in\mathbb{N},\ 0\le x\le \pi/2$, using Mathematical Induction.
The problem arises during the inductive step. What I've done so far, is
$$\sin(k+1)x=\sin(kx+x)=\sin kx\cos x + \sin x\cos kx.$$
Since $\cos x\le1,\ \forall x\in[0, \pi/2]$, we have that $\sin kx\cos x\le\sin kx\le k\sin x\ \text{(by the inductive hypothesis)}$, obtaining
$$\sin(k+1)x\le k\sin x +\sin x\cos kx.$$
I need to prove that the last term is $\le\sin x$, but I'm not sure that what I've done until now is correct, since $\sin$ and $\cos$ are nonnegative for $x$, but not for $kx$.

If the statement to prove had the modulus, it would be easier to be proven.

Comment: Cool problem...

Comment: It doesn't matter if $\cos kx$ is positive or negative.  It it will always be $\le +1$.  So as long as $\sin x \ge 0$ you will always have $k\sin x - \sin x \le k\sin x + \sin x\cdot \cos kx \le k\sin x + \sin x$.   It's true that if $0< d \le 1$ then $M + d \le M+1$ but even if $d\le 0 < 1$ you will *still* have $M+d \le M+1$ (because $M+d \le M < M+1$).  [Note: no-one *ever* implied that $M\le M+d \le M+1$.  Only $M +d\le M+1$ was stated. Likewise no-one ever said $\color{red}{k\sin x \le} k\sin x +\sin x\cos kx\le (k+1)\sin x$.  Only the part not in red is assumed.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You also have that $\sin x\ge0$ and from $\cos kx\le1$ you conclude that
$$
\sin x\cos kx\le\sin x
$$
So this is the easy step.

The issue is to prove $\sin kx\cos x\le k\sin x$, where your argument is faulty. But this is not a real problem: if $\sin kx\le0$, then $\sin kx\cos x\le0\le k\sin x$. If $\sin kx>0$, then from $\cos x\le 1$ you obtain $\sin kx\cos x\le \sin kx$ and you can apply the induction hypothesis.

Comment: Yes, this makes sense.